# How would I use this Factory class and whats the point?

Tags: c#, class, methods, factory, factory-pattern

This is my first ever post to SO and am very new to C# with most of my IT experience in databases. I am starting to look at some of our code and would like to understand how I would use this class and it methods for resusability purposes.

```
public class FileCreator
{
    public string Territory { get; set; }
    public string CV { get; set; }
    public string AdDate { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Advertiser { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public decimal SumOfSpend { get; set; }
    public decimal SumOfVolume { get; set; }
    public string Spots { get; set; }
    public string PageNumber { get; set; }

    internal static List<FileCreator> Create(DataSet data)
    {
        var result = new List<FileCreator>();

        if (data.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            result = Create(data.Tables[0]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static List<FileCreator> Create(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var result = new List<FileCreator>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            result.Add(Create(row));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static FileCreator Create(DataRow row)
    {
        var fileCreator = new FileCreator();

        fileCreator.Territory = (row["Territory"].ToString());
        fileCreator.CV = row["CV"].ToString();
        fileCreator.AdDate = row["Ad_date"].ToString();
        fileCreator.Category = row["Category"].ToString();
        fileCreator.Advertiser = row["Advertiser"].ToString();
        fileCreator.Brand = row["Brand"].ToString();
        fileCreator.SumOfSpend = Convert.ToDecimal(row["SumOfSpend"].ToString());
        fileCreator.SumOfVolume = Convert.ToDecimal(row["SumOfVolume"].ToString());
        fileCreator.Spots = row["Spots"].ToString();
        fileCreator.PageNumber = row["Page Number"].ToString();

        return fileCreator;
    }
}
```

Why not just create a new instance of a datatable i.e. var dt = new Datatable()?

I must be missing the point of this approach. How will I benefit from this approach when I normally just create multiple datatables?

Go easy. It's my first post

Thank you

Comment: Dont think there's any Factory Pattern here. All this piece of code is doing is. Using ADO.NET - you fetch records in a dataset/datatable. These records match with entity FileCreator and so this piece of code is helping you convert a set of db records (datatable) to a collection of (List<T>) objects.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow :) what's the reason to tag this question as *factory* and *factory-pattern*? as @PrateekShrivastava wrote, this class does not implement the factory pattern. The **FileCreator** purpose is to encapsulate the logic for creating the *FileCreator* object and separate it from the logic that performs the actual call to the database. So with this implementation you achieve 2 things - encapsulation and separation of concerns

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that you are accepting a concrete type -`DataTable dataTable` which couples you tightly to `ADO.NET` and if you decide to change the way you retrieve your data from the DB (for example switch to Entity Framework) then all those methods will have to be changed, but I've seen this approach before, mostly in older projects where ORMs were not that widely spread.

Comment: This is not a good fit for stack overflow, application design and explain me this pattern type questions are opinionated and far from concrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of this is get a strongly typed class instead of relying on hard-coded strings to get the data out and then casting everything to the type you are expecting.  Instead, its taking data from the Datatable and transforming it to a "Dto" (Data Transfer Object) where you know all the properties (columns) that exist and their types because they are explicitly declared.  There is no guessing! :)

While the given approach here works, I hope it is more for legacy sake.  It is more efficient to simply create this Dto class directly instead of creating a Datatable and then mapping it.